# Is a binary semaphore needed for synchronization of a counting semaphore?

Tags: synchronization, semaphore, sysv-ipc

My professor says that if you have a counting semaphore (specifically, a System V semaphore), there can be synchronization problems if two processes try to access the semaphore at the same time, so you need to mediate access to the counting semaphore with a separate binary semaphore.

I thought that the whole point of semaphores is that if two process try to access a semaphore at the same time, the kernel automatically synchronizes access. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

Yes system V semaphores will be adjusted atomically and access to them is definitely thread safe without a further semaphore. What isn't atomic is the *creation* and *initialisation* of the semaphore which must be done before any processes try to access and adjust it.